# logrus wrapper for standard go log.Logger

Tags: go, logging, logrus

I have a struct requesting a standard `log.Logger` as parameter for log messages. From the zap logger a wrapper is provided by [NewStdLogAt](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#NewStdLogAt):

```golang
stdLogAt, err := zap.NewStdLogAt(&s.log, zap.ErrorLevel)
```

Now I have to use this module in a `logrus` logger environment. I have not found `logrus` providing an implementation for `log.Logger`. What are my possible approaches? Is there an implementation available?

Comment: Can you share a piece of code ?

Comment: Well, since I have not found a solution I have no code. I added the zap approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Logrus documentation seems to suggest creating a new `log.Logger` using the result of the `Writer` function which Logrus [loggers](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sirupsen/logrus) and [entries](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sirupsen/logrus#Entry.Writer) provide.

```
w := logrusLogger.Writer()

// or to define an error level:
// logrusLogger.WriterLevel(logrus.ErrorLevel)

// note that you are responsible for closing the writer
defer w.Close() 

stdlibLogger := log.New(w, "", 0)
```

I have inferred this from the "Logger as an io.Writer" section on [this page](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sirupsen/logrus).